# Import Data frame value to Dictionary

Tags: python, tabula

I have a code to extract the table data from pdf, I want to convert the data frame to a dictionary, if I mention the output as JSON in tabula it gives the coordinates also which is not required. I want only the data present in the table. if the data frame is converted to a dictionary , I can go up with other processing work

```
from tabula import read_pdf
from tabulate import tabulate
import pandas as pd

df = read_pdf("http://www.uncledavesenterprise.com/file/health/Food%20Calories%20List.pdf",multiple_tables=True,pages='3' ,pandas_options={'header':None},guess = False)
print (df)
```

Comment: You can use df.to_dict() or df.to_dict(orient='records')

Comment: @PramoteKuacharoen  it gives me this error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_json'

Comment: You have to do it on your data frame, not a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `df.to_dict()` to convert the dataframe to dictionary. You can use this method directly or also give some arguments which can be checked [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) for pandas v1.0.5 or [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) for pandas v0.23.4 . You can also use `df.to_json()` for converting the dataframe to JSON. Information regarding arguments can be found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_json) and [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_json) for v1.0.5 and v0.23.4 respectively.

Comment: @ devShaurya it gives me this error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_json'

Comment: @ChirstyCR_007 First convert the df variable into pandas dataframe, using pd.DataFrame(df). You can check regarding that on the pandas documentation. Then use my answer.